# Disabling/deleting Close(X) button of ajax dialog form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am calling ajax to load partial view on a div on submission of form. It work fine. Partial view load correctly at define div. Now I need to delete/disable close(X) button of that ajax popup dialog. How can I do that?

Comment: You might like to post relevant parts of your code - it generally makes it easier for people answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a hidden div that you bring to the front using shadow box or some other utility like it that looks like a dialog.  The dialog box can not have the close button removed for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try this i think it will probably help you..

```
$("yourdivid").dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide()
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?